# I want to parse the csv contents into an array using php? But my outuput is not proper?

Tags: php, arrays, csv

```
<?php error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);

$csv_file = file_get_contents($argv[1]); 
$getdata = fopen($argv[1],"r");  
if ($getdata == FALSE) {
    echo "Insert the proper csv filename" ; 
} 
while (!feof($getdata) ) {
    $data = fgetcsv($getdata, 1000); 
    print_r($data); 
} 
fclose($getdata); 
?>
```

this is the code that i am using.

The output is shown in this way

```
 Array (
     [0] => name
     [1] => email
     [2] => contact
     [3] => address 
    ) 
Array (
     [0] => santos
     [1] => santos@gmail.com
     [2] => 1684218942
     [3] => hennur )
```

but i want it in this format

```
Array[1] (
     [0] => name
     [1] => email
     [2] => contact
     [3] => address 
    ) 
Array[2] (
     [0] => santosh
     [1] => santoshm9916@gmail.com
     [2] => 9035619733
     [3] => hennur 
    )
```

Please help
can anyone tell me whats wrong with my code.

Comment: Show us the code you used to create this array please

Comment: Do you use fgetcsv? Or something else?

Comment: why do you want indexes starting from 1 ? usually, it's the same

Comment: where is your code

Comment: The number `9035619733` is too big for an integer value in a 32-bit version of PHP; perhaps you need to run a 64-bit version of PHP

Comment: Create a [mcve] please, or your question probably get closed soon

Answer (score 2):

I see two issues here:

first you are overwriting `$data` again and again at each iteration of the `while` loop.

Instead you want to stack all the rows in an array:

```
$data = array(); // here you initialize an empty array
while (!feof($getdata) ) {
    $data[] = fgetcsv($getdata, 1000); // the fetched row is pushed into the array
} 
print_r($data); // the resulting array (of arrays) is printed when file parsing is over
```

Note that this way the first row will be at index `0`. I think this should be the way to go as by default PHP arrays indexes are `0` based.

---

The second problem is that you expect a value to be `9035619733` but you get `1684218942`

As [Mark Baker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/324584/mark-baker) commented you're parsing a value `9035619733` that doesn't fit a 32 bit integer.

Unless you use a 64 bit version of PHP, `fgetcsv` is unable to parse correctly values that exceeds the 32 bit integer limits.

The value is not casted to **float** type as one may expect nor an error is emitted. `fgetcsv` just fails silently storing into the array a wrong value.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Get data from CSV file
$csv_file = file_get_contents($argv[1]);

//fopen() to read data
$getdata = fopen($argv[1], "r");

//is file submitted? 
if ($getdata == FALSE) {
    echo "Insert the proper csv filename";
}

//initialize an array
$row = array();


while (!feof($getdata)) {
    $row[] = fgetcsv($getdata, 1000); // push each row in array
}

// Print data
print_r($row);
```

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* it addresses the question.  Without that, your answer has much less educational value - remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.